# How many hashes create one Bitcoin?

Tags: mining-theory, hash, mining-reward, hashpower, sha256

Irrespective of the length of time required to calculate one hash, how many hash operations are required to produce one Bitcoin?

Answer (score 11):

These charts show the approximate network hash rate on the left axis:
  http://bitcoin.sipa.be/

We know the network adjusts for 25 new bitcoins per 10 minutes.

Together this provides enough info to give an approximate answer to your question:

```
hashes per bitcoin 
= (network hash rate) / (25 BTC per 10 minutes)
= (180 * Th / s) / (25 * BTC / (600 * s) )
= 180 * 600 / 25 * Th / s / BTC * s
= 2,700 Th / BTC
= 2,700,000,000,000,000 h/BTC
```

Comment: What does the 180 stand for?

Comment: That is read from the charts I linked to. It is the current network hash rate in terra-hash-per-second, as the charts show this number continually changes as miners come and go.

Comment: Thanks! I think I have to dig deeper into the function of BC to understand everything!

Comment: Enjoy the ride!

Comment: @powtac remember this result changes every 2160 blocks (roughly two weeks).

Comment: The current network hash rate is no longer "180 * Th / s" it's now "14000 * Th / s"!

Answer (score 2):

A good and simple website to calculate how much bitcoin can be created with what machine can be found at: http://www.alcula.com/calculators/finance/bitcoin-mining/

Answer (score 1):

Difficulty changes regularly, but there are calculators that take all current factors into account:

https://www.cryptocompare.com/mining/calculator/btc?HashingPower=15&HashingUnit=TH%2Fs&PowerConsumption=0&CostPerkWh=0

As of today (17 Jan 2017): a theoretical 1,581 TH/s (equivalent of running a hundred Antminer S9's) will return 1 BTC in a day.

Tomorrow, it will be different.